# How can I find the start and end pixels cropped image?

Tags: c#, image

I am a beginner programmer,I split an image into 16 parts (I'm making a picture puzzle game) And each one is inside a picturebox  And randomly places them have 
changed Now I want to know the beginning and end of each image I cut it connects to another image (I mean, any image Continue other). Is such a thing possible? Do you have a better idea?

```
namespace ImagePuzzelGame
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Point move;
        bool isDragging = false;
        public Dictionary<int, Point> pics
        {
            set;
            get;
        }
        private Point _defaultlocation = new Point(306, 306);
        Random rnd = new Random();
        public Point DefaultLocation
        {
            get
            {
                return _defaultlocation;
            }

            set
            {
                _defaultlocation = value;
            }
        }
        public List<PictureBox> picPuzzle
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public Bitmap newImage
        {
            get; set;
        }
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            pics = new Dictionary<int, Point>()
            {
                {1,new Point(0,0) },
                {2,new Point(100,0) },
                {3,new Point(200,0) },
                {4,new Point(300,0) },
                {5,new Point(400,0) },
                {6,new Point(0,119) },
                {7,new Point(100,119) },
                {8,new Point(200,119) },
                {9,new Point(300,119) },
                {10,new Point(400,119) },
                {11,new Point(0,325) },
                {12,new Point(100,325) },
                {13,new Point(200,325) },
                {14,new Point(300,325) },
                {15,new Point(400,325) },
            };
            List<PictureBox> picturebox = new List<PictureBox>
            {
                pictureBox1,pictureBox2,pictureBox3,pictureBox4,pictureBox5,pictureBox6,pictureBox7,
                pictureBox8,pictureBox9,pictureBox10,pictureBox11,pictureBox12,pictureBox13,pictureBox14,pictureBox15,pictureBox16
            };

            picPuzzle = picturebox;

          resizeImage();
           cropImage();
           shufflePuzzle();
        }

        public void shufflePuzzle()
        {
            int numberSelect;
            int index = 0;
            Point virtualLocation;
            List<int> selected = new List<int>();
            while (selected.Count < picPuzzle.Count)
            {
                int randomSelectPuzzle = rnd.Next(0, 16);
                if (selected.Contains(randomSelectPuzzle))
                {
                    randomSelectPuzzle = rnd.Next(0, 16);
                }
                else
                {
                    numberSelect = randomSelectPuzzle;
                    virtualLocation = new Point(picPuzzle[numberSelect].Location.X, picPuzzle[numberSelect].Location.Y);

                    picPuzzle[numberSelect].Location = new Point(DefaultLocation.X, DefaultLocation.Y);
                    DefaultLocation = virtualLocation;
                    selected.Add(randomSelectPuzzle);
                }
            }
        }

        public void resizeImage()
        {
            Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(320, 320);
            Bitmap srcImage = new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\bbmm\Desktop\images\lukas-graham.jpg");
            using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
            {
                gr.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                gr.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                gr.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                gr.DrawImage(srcImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, 320, 320));
            }

            this.newImage = newImage;

            try
            {
                Bitmap bt = new Bitmap(newImage);
                bt.Save(@"E:\img\pic.jpg");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }    
        }

        public void cropImage()
        {
            var filename = @"E:\img\pic.jpg";

            Rectangle cropRect;
            Bitmap[] src = new Bitmap[16];
            Bitmap[] target = new Bitmap[16];
            int x = 0, y = 0;
            int index = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                {
                    if (index == 17)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    cropRect = new Rectangle(new Point(x, y), new Size(new Point(100, 100)));
                    src[index] = Image.FromFile(filename) as Bitmap;
                    target[index] = new Bitmap(cropRect.Width, cropRect.Height);
                    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(target[index]))
                    {
                        g.DrawImage(src[index], new Rectangle(0, 0, target[index].Width, target[index].Height), cropRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                    }
                    picPuzzle[index].Image = target[index];

                    x += 100;
                    index++;

                }
                y += 100;
                x = 0;
            }

        }

        public Point HoldLocation
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        private void pictureBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            isDragging = true;
            move = e.Location;
        }

        public List<PictureBox> pastePics { get; set; }

        private void pictureBox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {


            if (isDragging)
            {
                PictureBox pb = (PictureBox)sender;

                pb.Left += e.X - move.X;
                pb.Top += e.Y - move.Y;
                pb.BringToFront();
            }  

        }  

        private void pictureBox_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            isDragging = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to know the solution? If so, the best course of action is of course to keep that information while you have it. You can use a naming schem or the PB's Tag property etc..

Comment: or do you mean that you want to check if the parts overlap or align? checking location and size would help then

Comment: I don't see `PuzzlePiece` class where you store data needed to: 1) crumble the puzzle 2) solve the puzzle. It could contain cropped image, position in solved puzzle, position of piece on the board and angle or rotation. Then you take big image, crop it and store as `List<PuzzlePiece>`, randomize angle and position on board = ready to be solved.